# Stimulsoft Group Header misplaced

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

I have a report in Stimulsoft, with a Group Header, a Header and a Data Band.
in Stimulsoft designer I put Group Header on top of Header and Data Band, But in out put the Header goes up the Group Header and the design does not show well.
In web sites said that Group Header always goes up the Header, regardless where they are placed. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution, I put my Header Texts into Header Group and removed Header, then make Group Header "Print on all pages".